# CakePHP adding class to dateTime input

Tags: cakephp, html-helper

I use `FormHelper::dateTime` for `DATE` format.

Anybody know how to add each other class for days, months and years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below cakephp code will generate same dropdown box with given default value and the post data will be same :

```
echo $this->Form->day('Profile.dob', array('empty'=>'Day','class' => 'cls-day'));
echo $this->Form->month('Profile.dob', array('empty'=>'Month','class' => 'cls-month'));
echo $this->Form->year('Profile.dob', 1950, date('Y'),array('empty'=>'Year','class' => 'cls-year'));
```